# Web Storage API and Javascript - Undefined Error

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-storage

I've been trying to get style changes on my html page to get stored using this API. Im pretty new at this so im not exactly sure what the problem is. The style changes work when I select the menu item, but if I refresh or close the window, they don't save.

EDIT: I've moved away from trying to get them to save but instead having the last style used stored using localStorage then using a switch to run the function for the last saved style. However i am getting an undefined error when trying to get the last saved value.

Here's the JS:

```
//Style 1
function style1(){
    var vP = document.getElementById('video_container');
    var bG = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    var banner = document.getElementById('top_header');
    var body = document.getElementById('body_div');

    vP.style.backgroundColor = ('black');
    bG[0].style.background = "url('images/bg/bg1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
    sidebar.style.display = ('block');  
    banner.style.display = ('block'); 
    body.style.marginTop = ('190px');  

    var selectedStyle = "style";
    var value = 's1'; 
    newItem(selectedStyle,value);
}

//Style 2
function style2(){
    var vP = document.getElementById('video_container');
    var bG = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    var banner = document.getElementById('top_header');
    var body = document.getElementById('body_div');

    vP.style.backgroundColor = get_random_color();
    bG[0].style.background = "url('images/bg/bg"+randNum()+".jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
    sidebar.style.display = ('block');  
    banner.style.display = ('block');  
    body.style.marginTop = ('190px');

    var selectedStyle = 'style'; 
    var value = 's2';
    newItem(selectedStyle,value);
}

//Style 3
function style3(){
    var vP = document.getElementById('video_container');
    var bG = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    var banner = document.getElementById('top_header');
    var body = document.getElementById('body_div');

    vP.style.backgroundColor = get_random_color();
    bG[0].style.background = "url('images/bg/bg"+randNum()+".jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
    sidebar.style.display = ('none');  
    banner.style.display = ('none'); 
    body.style.marginTop = ('80px');  

    var selectedStyle = 'style'; 
    var value = 's3';
    newItem(selectedStyle,value); 
}


//-------------Web Storage API stuff-------------//
window.addEventListener('load',initiate);

function initiate(){
    window.addEventListener('storage', storagechange);
    show();
}
function newItem(id,style){

    localStorage.setItem(id,style);    
}
function show(){   
    var x = localStorage.key(0);
    var y = localStorage.getItem(x);
    var z=2;
    alert(y); //used to test what value i would get, it says undefined 

    switch (y) {
        case 's3':
            style3();
            break;
        case 's2':
            style2();
            break;
        case 's1':
        default:
            style1();
            break;
    } 

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sideMenu" >
    <ul class="bmenu">
        <li id="f1" onclick="style1()">Style 1</li> <!--turn sidebar on/off-->
        <li id='f2' onclick="style2()">Style 2</li> <!--randomize vidcontain border-->
        <li id='f3' onclick="style3()">Style 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you think `localStorage.getItem(0);` does?

Comment: Im trying to get the first value (function) stored locally?

Comment: hmm, well first you can only store strings in localStorage, second you aren't assigning it to anything once you've got it.

Comment: you mean i should have something like Var X = localStorage.key(0);

Comment: sure, although I would be more interested in getItem than key, but actually assigning the value and doing something with it will be a good start.

Comment: from what i've seen in a past example, they set the key to a variable and created another variable and passed it through the getItem(X) so i'll try doing that and apply it to the answer @robertc suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably do save, but at no point in your `initiate()` function do you call any of the functions to set the style.

Also, with the way you're setting the values in local storage - every time you select a style from the menu and close the window you're adding an item to the store, here is the call with variables replaced with values:

```
localStorage.setItem('f3','style3()');
```

If you do this three times having selected the three different styles then you will simply have three entries in local storage, `f1`, `f2` and `f3`.  You never remove any items, so it's hard to see how this is going to help you determine which the last selected style was.  What you should be doing is something more like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('savedStyle','f3');
```

Then in `initiate()`:

```
var savedStyle = localStorage.getItem('savedStyle');

switch (savedStyle) {
    case 'f3':
        style3();
        break;
    case 'f2':
        style2();
        break;
    case 'f1':
    default:
        style1();
        break;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post and tried to implement what you suggested. I used an alert box to  display what I was getting from the localStorage but it's giving me an undefined error

Comment: @Batman What you've done is not what I've suggested.  Why are you doing `localStorage.key()`?  You already know what the key is, it's what you used to store the item in the first place, as per my example above.

Comment: Yea you're right. When I removed that line it started working. Thank you.